# git removes new file

Tags: git, merge

git removes a new file (I'll call it missing.txt) and I doen't understand why. After searching Google and Stackoverflow this seems to be common, but the reasons why this happens very specific to the exact flow. I'd like to understand what happens in my case to prevent it in the future.

In the image below I've captured the relevant commits

[git history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5so3s.png)

- **c670a66 adds `missing.txt`** (filename does not exist in other branches, nor has it ever existed)
- ad147f8 (merge) unrelated change in 1 other file
- 443db84 changes `missing.txt`
- eaf13a2 (merge) unrelated changes and new other files
- 5736abc changes `missing.txt`
- d9aad89 (merge) unrelated changes
- e16cee9 (merge) unrelated changes and new other files
- **4a22dc3 (merge) removes `missing.txt`**

Comment: Well, hard to say with what you provided, but it seems a blue branch started before `c670a66` was merged before `4a22dc3`. Could be this one which removes your file ?

Comment: @Arount, no; the only commits that touch missing.txt are mentioned in my topic start. The file has never existed before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your file was removed in the another branch you merged, probably by someone else. Anyway it can be easily recovered, by checking out to any commit before the file was deleted.

```
git checkout e16cee9

# Just copy your file now
```

Comment: Thanks. Recovery is no issue, however. I'd like to understand why this happens in the first place

Comment: Most likely someone in the another branch deleted the file, and when you merged the changes the change was reflected in your branch as well.